# Had a query that worked but now doesn't

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I made a copy of the spreadsheet that [I'm working on here.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ULe6ewKWXJwyoCLLAIH6mzD8T_3J1YkRSM4x9k42XtI/edit?usp=sharing)

The query that I have on on the sheets "DSM", "DiveTank", "WarmUp", "Teach" all have pretty much the same query.  That worked before but now doesn't.

```
=QUERY(WaterTests!A:AO,"SELECT D,E,J,H,I,G,K,L,M,N,A,B,C WHERE G is not null OR H is not null OR I is not null OR J is not null OR K is not null OR L is not null OR M is not null OR N is not null ORDER BY D,E ASC")
```

This `query` only grabs the header row and stops. I have 103 rows of data that are not null. It should work.

The only thing I changed was clearing out the original data that was entered in via the form. So that I could put in two weeks' worth of dummy data.  Which is in the "WaterTest" sheet.

I'm hitting a wall on this.

Comment: I did already.  Im just starting fresh on a new sheet.  It seems to be working perfectly on it. Just hate not knowing why.

Comment: Sorry when I said I did already. I just highlighted and pressed delete to delete any values.  However when I deleted the rows like you mentioned it now works.  weird!  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

pnuts gave the answer that I needed in his comment to my question.  I dont know how to select it as an answer so. I'll just quote him.

> Try deleting the 'spare' rows at the bottom of WaterTests. –  pnuts